# Why can't queries be starred from the queries list?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, data-explorer

I was wondering why do I have to navigate to a query in order to star it, in [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com). I can imagine an answer like "how do you know you like it, if you haven't run it or even looked at it?", but:

1. How do you know I haven't navigated to the query *before*?
2. Why is that important, after all? How is it bad if I want to star a query just after reading its title?

In case there are good reasons not to eliminate this restriction, I believe the star icon (which *screams* CLICK ME, in my opinion) should be avoided on query list pages, e.g. in favor of some text like "stars" or "favorited".

Comment: `"how do you know you like it, if you haven't run it or even looked at it?"` -- I think that's exactly the reason.

Comment: @Robert that was my guess, in fact, but what about the rest of my question? How bad could it be, letting users star queries without seeing them?
And in case it **is** bad, don't you think that actual stars in queries list pages are misleading, even with their mouseover text? To me, that's basically a design flaw.

Comment: I figured that, given the first assumption, it was not implemented because doing so increases the application's complexity without substantial benefit.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I still believe the star looks "too clickable", though. Well, since nobody complained before, maybe it's just me… We shall see.