# SEDE favorite button fails silently when not logged in

Tags: bug, data-explorer, bookmarks

I was trying to bookmark/favorite [this interesting Proof of Concept](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1584283/proof-of-concept-for-using-a-procedural-approach-once-you-have-rows-from-a-set) on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, but clicking the favorite button

[image]

did not do *anything*. Of course, I should have realized SEDE logged me out (but it's Monday morning here, blame the lack of coffee), but I'd expect at least a message telling me to log in before using that feature.

Comment: I think that is the only place where we have an action that is only valid when logged in. I would have to check but IIRC there is no common message popup dialog anywhere else in the code base. If I were to take this on you would get an `alert('Have a coffee and login');`. Awesome UX.

Comment: there is also this older  related FR to have the favorite icon be clickable from the query list: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97246/why-cant-queries-be-starred-from-the-queries-list maybe this and that makes sense to combine when implementing.